# Possible to speed up distribute crash log to Xcode?

Tags: ios

If user select distribute crash log with App Developers, we can see code level analysis where crash happens. But need to wait for log half a day.

If device is in our control, could we speed up this process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it's a debug / development build you should be able to extract the logs through XCode by connecting the iOS device to your Mac. In XCode open `Window > Devices and Simulators` and select the device.

For App Store / Enterprise builds you may want to consider a 3rd party exception / crash reporting tool which supports iOS. For example:

- [Bugsnag](https://www.bugsnag.com/platforms/ios-crash-reporting/)
- [Sentry](https://sentry.io/for/cocoa/) - Available as a hosted product or open source
- [Firebase Crashlytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/crashlytics/)

Comment: What if logs are from app installed from TestFlight?

Comment: If you have physical access to the device you should be able to extract the logs. See this note from Apple for further details: https://developer.apple.com/library/content/qa/qa1747/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40011341-CH1-GETTING_CRASH_LOGS_AND_CONSOLE_OUTPUT-GETTING_CRASH_LOGS_AND_CONSOLE_OUTPUT_FROM_A_DEVICE_USING_XCODE